# What does 1 Corinthians 9:17 mean?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul

1 Corinthians 9:17 (NASB)

> For if I do this voluntarily, I have a reward; but if against my will, I have a stewardship entrusted to me.

What does Paul mean when he compares voluntarily preaching the Gospel with preaching “against [his] will”? What does it mean for him to preach the Gospel against his will, and what does that have to do with stewardship entrusted to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read "ἄκων" as ["unwilling"](https://www.biblestudytools.com/lexicons/greek/nas/akon.html) as [most](https://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/9-17.htm) current version do, then that makes this a bit easier to understand what he means.

Paul is not claiming that his preaching is unwilling, but is offering a hypothetical: **but if** (εἰ). What he is saying, that his will is irrelevant on whether he preaches the Bible or not - he is obliged to since that (preaching the gospel) is his obligation (or stewardship.)

This serves as a contrast to that which he has a choice in, and which is the core thing he speaks of here - Paul's refusal to accept support from the Corinthians.

> 15 But I have used none of these things. And I have not written these
> things so that it will be done so in my case; for it would be better
> for me to die than that. No one shall make my boast an empty one! 16
> For if I preach the gospel, I have nothing to boast about, for I am
> under compulsion; for woe to me if I do not preach the gospel. 17 For
> if I do this voluntarily, I have a reward; but if against my will, I
> have been entrusted with a commission nonetheless. 18 What, then, is
> my reward? That, when I preach the gospel, I may offer the gospel
> without charge, so as not to make full use of my right in the gospel.

Paul can boast of not being a burden to the Corinthians, since that is his choice and liberty. In contrast, he is obliged to preach to the gospel: "woe to [him] if [he] do[es] not preach the gospel"

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you! The comparison of preaching the Gospel v. Receiving money from preaching makes so much sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1 Co 9:16 makes emphasis that Paul (by God's Spirit of conviction) must preach the gospel.  This is fulfilling the Royal Law and loving your neighbor as yourself.
1 Co 9:17 means If he does this willingly (a cheerful giver) of the gospel then he has a reward in heaven, but if his fleshly will desires not to be so cheerful it will be hard for him to properly give out the gospel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).